# Autofill Google Doc from Form Find Last Row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I followed a youtube video to create a Google Apps Script that will autofill a Google Doc (template) with responses from a Form, on Submission as the trigger.  I had to add a number of calculated columns to calculate further based on the answer filled out in the Form submission.  I need to have all columns filled to the Google Doc.

I am pasting the full code below, I believe I am close.  The bold part is what I know I need to update, but I am unsure how.  Currently the script loops through all rows of data and creates a new Google Doc for each row.  I need it to find the last/most recent row of data from the spreadsheet (would be the most recent form submission) and populate the Doc with that data.  I have looked everywhere trying to find a solution- any help is appreciated!

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e){
var PersonName = e.values[1];
var Month = e.values [2];
var ShowName = e.values [3];
var Sale = e.values [4];
var BuyType = e.values [5];
var Budget = e.values [6];
var Products = e.values [7];
var TermMonths = e.values [8];
var Title = e.values [9];
var Assets = e.values [10];
var NumberofShows = e.values [11];
var NumberofSales = e.values [12];
var ListSize = e.values [13];
var Agency = e.values [14];
var DataCadence = e.values [15];
var Other = e.values [16];
var AdditionalNotes = e.values [17];

**var rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
rows.forEach(function(row){
var ContractID = row [18];
var Term = row [19];
var StartDate = row [20];
var EndDate = row [21];
var CustomerCost = row [22];
var CostShow = row [23];
var Cost = row [24];
var TotalEngagements = row [25];
var CostSplit = row [26];
var TotalEmails = row [27];
var CostData = row [28];**

var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("9fu1jGgpaQ");
var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("15h3GnG");

var copy = templateFile.makeCopy('Name' + BrName, templateResponseFolder);
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
var body = doc.getBody();

body.replaceText("{{Name of Manufacturer}}", Manufacturer);
body.replaceText("{{Name of Brand}}", BrandDrugName);
body.replaceText("{{Name of Products}}", ProductsPurchased);
body.replaceText("{{Start Date}}", StartDate);
body.replaceText("{{End Date}}", CalculatedEndDate);
body.replaceText("{{Title of Sponsorship}}", SeriesSponsorshipTitle);
body.replaceText("{{Name Generic}}", ClientAssets);
body.replaceText("{{Number of Videos}}", NumberofVideos);
body.replaceText("{{Cost Video Int}}", CustomerVideoIntegrationCost);
body.replaceText("{{Total Video Eng}}", TotalVideoEngagements);
body.replaceText("{{Video Eng}}", VideoEngSplit);
body.replaceText("{{Video Eng 2}}", VideoEngSplit);
body.replaceText("{{Target List Size}}", TargetListSize);
body.replaceText("{{Cost Video Eng}}", CostVideoEngagement);
body.replaceText("{{Total Email Eng}}", TotalEmailEngagements);
body.replaceText("{{Cost Email Eng}}", CostEmailEngagement);
body.replaceText("{{Target Size}}", TargetSize);
body.replaceText("{{Data Cadence}}", DataCadence);
body.replaceText("{{Cost Data}}", CostDataTransfer);

doc.saveAndClose();

})
}
```

Comment: If you only need answers from the form, you have can get all of them in `e.values`. You do not need to do get values from the spreadsheet with `var rows = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your code block

```
**var rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
... 
var CostData = row [28];**
```

to the following

```
let entryRow = e.range.getRow(),     
  rowData = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('... yourSheetName here ...').getRange(entryRow,17,1,11).getDisplayValues().flat(),
  ContractID                    = rowData[0],
  CalculatedTerm                = rowData[1],
  StartDate                     = rowData[2],
  CalculatedEndDate             = rowData[3],
  CustomerVideoIntegrationCost  = rowData[4],
  CostVideoEngagement           = rowData[5],
  CostEmailEngagement           = rowData[6],
  TotalVideoEngagements         = rowData[7],
  VideoEngSplit                 = rowData[8],
  TotalEmailEngagements         = rowData[9],
  CostData                      = rowData[10];
```

but the question is whether the formulas in the `Q:Z` columns on your sheet will have time to process the information before you get the data with `.getDisplayValues()`. You might find it easier to translate all those formulas into a script and process the data from the form inside the script without using the formulas on the sheet

Comment: Thanks so much for taking a look!  I was wondering the same thing about whether the formulas will have time to process the information.  The above does not seem to be pulling in any values from my calculated columns either :(  I would try writing the formulas in the script but they are complicated as they are referencing an alternate tab to pull in various information via VLOOKUP, MATCH/INDEX, etc.

Comment: The original script with the ForEach above was pulling in values from the columns, however it was looping through and creating a new doc for each row.  Wondering if there are any modifications I can make to that not using the ForEach that would work?  Thanks again